# Determine 404 Requests from Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights configured for a web application of mine, and I see that I have a surprising amount of 404 errors.  Is there a way for me to use AI to drill in and find what page(s) are being requested that Im returning a 404 on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open portal.azure.com. Open your Service overview blade for your application. Click on failed requests and you will see the info for each failed request. 
Getting started [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/#get-started).